# Intel HD4000 slow graphics performance on external display

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, external-monitor

I am using ubuntu 13.10.

I have a Dell Latitude E6430 laptop. It has two graphic adapters, Intel HD 4000 and nvidia NVS 5200M with optimus technology.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] (rev a1)
```

I have very bad graphics performance on my external display connected to my laptop via HDMI. 
I thought nvidia driver would fix it and I tried different techniques to install NVIDIA driver and they all failed, in the last 3 days I have reinstalled ubuntu like 30 times.

So I gave up on the idea of setting up nvidia graphics addapter. Since I use ubuntu only for work I don't need high graphics performance.

Ijust need a way to configure my external display with the intel hd 4000 graphics card so the mousepointer would not leave the trail and the graphics performance would be acceptable.

Thank you.

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
1440x900       59.9  
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1152x864       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
1680x1050      59.9  
1600x900       60.0  
1280x1024      60.0  
1280x800       59.9  
1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
1440x576i      50.1  
1024x768       60.0  
1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
800x600        60.3  
720x576        50.0  
720x480        60.0     59.9  
640x480        60.0     59.9  
VGA-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1024x768 (0x55)   65.0MHz
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
800x600 (0x58)   40.0MHz
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
640x480 (0x5d)   25.2MHz
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set up two displays in a computer with intel hd graphics 4000 + mvidia geforce 710M (bumblebee installed). I've just plugin and configure them by the display settings of unity...And it's working.

The only difference with yours is I'm using VGA cable instead of HDMI. Maybe you could try plug-in through a VGA cable.